Safe wallet web doesn't pick up our network due to old version of api-kit
Our networks are part of the safe-api-kit v2.4.6.
In the latest release of safe-wallet-web the version of api-kit is not the latest (it uses api-kit: ^2.4.4), which is causing creation of safe to fail.
I've tried building safe-wallet-web locally and use that instead of the docker image from docker hub, and it works when I use api-kit v2.4.6. When will the dependencies be bumped to use the latest version?

It looks like it was just done: https://github.com/safe-global/safe-wallet-web/issues/4292

@ruby_newbie yes it exists in the dev container but not when using the latest release, is it advisable to use the dev tagged container for prod or wait for latest to pick these up in next release

That is a question that your organization should answer ideally.  In my opinion I wouldn't upgrade the dependency until it is stable on 'latest' and doesn't break my build.  If someone wants to use 'dev' I would expect a really compelling reason to do so.

This update will be included in next week's release. You can use the version built locally in the meantime. Hope your use case can wait a few days 
Thank you for understanding; please let me know if I can help with anything else. Best, Louis
